# Radar diagram in R - variable values not visible in radar diagram and labels too long

Tags: r, variables, radar-chart

I am trying to create a radar diagram in R. How to fix these 2 issues?

1- Variable values are not visible

2- Variable labels are on top of each other

And another question:

3 - How to set up a gradient colour background (from dark grey to light grey) in my graph?

My data:

```
> dput(df_radar_final_new)
structure(list(`My input is well received in this clinical area.` = 58, 
    `In this clinical area, it is difficult to speak up when I perceive a problem with patient care.` = 46, 
    `Disagreements in this clinical area are resolved appropriately (i.e., not who is right but what is best for the patient).` = 69, 
    `I have the support I need from my colleagues and other staff groups to care for patients.` = 32, 
    `It is easy for staff here to ask questions when there is something that they do not understand.` = 63), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

My code:

```
install.packages("fmsb")
library(fmsb)

par(mar=c(1, 2, 2, 1)) #decrease default margin
radarchart(df_radar_final_new, maxmin=FALSE)
```

Current output:
[image]

Image 1 - After running code provided below:
[image]

Image 2 - What I would like to have:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can break text by writing `\n` after words to break the text.

```
df <- structure(list(`My input is well received in this clinical area.` = 58, 
               `In this clinical area\n, it is difficult to speak up\n when I perceive a problem with patient care.` = 46, 
               `Disagreements in this\n clinical area are resolved appropriately\n (i.e., not who is right but what is best for the patient).` = 69, 
               `I have the support\n I need from my colleagues and other\n staff groups to care for patients.` = 32, 
               `It is easy for staff here\n to ask questions when there\n is something that they do\n not understand.` = 63), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

df

library(fmsb)

par(mar=c(1, 2, 2, 1)) #decrease default margin
radarchart(df, maxmin=FALSE, axistype=3, pty=32, plty=1, axislabcol="red", na.itp=FALSE,
           title="(no points, axis=3, na.itp=FALSE)")
```

I played around a bit, you have to change the `axislabcol` to see your values. Here is the documentation: https://rdrr.io/cran/fmsb/man/radarchart.html => I was not able to find a way to change the background color.